# Android - layout border, old "boarder" still visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i have a constraint layout, where i added a border like so:

**custom_info_window.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/info_window_boarder"
    >
...
...
```

**info_window_boarder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

but i still see the old "boarder" (the white square boarder). How do i get rid of that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was setting up the Info Window stuff in `getInfoContents` instead of `getInfoWindow`.

`getInfoContents` will give you the default white box. If you want a custom one like i did, you will need to do everything in `getInfoWindow` like so:

```
     mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
        override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker?): View {
            val row: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null)
            val tvAddress: TextView = row.findViewById(R.id.textView_iw_address)
            val tvTime: TextView = row.findViewById(R.id.textView_iw_time)

            tvAddress.text = marker?.title
            tvTime.text = marker?.snippet

            return row            }

        override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker?): View? {
            //put in here, if you just want the default info window
            return null
        }
    })
```